# why can't I open my commands or chat

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whenever I try to open my commands by pressing / nothing happens. Same with opening my chat, nothing happens. What would cause this?

Comment: Have you tried pressing the T key which is the default or checked your options to see if they key hadn't been rebinded to another key, the commands is the same as the chat also

Answer (score 7):

Double check that your chat is not disabled under multiplayer settings. Also check your key bindings.

Comment: I just found out that I had my chat set on hidden, so that's why it didn't work